# Why is the geonames not loading?

Tags: grass-gis, vector, geonames

I want to import a geonames file. I downloaded the geonames .txt file from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

I used:
`v.in.geonames input=PH.txt output=ph`

but it displayed this error:
`ERROR: File 'C:UsersRhenDesktopPHPH.txt' not found`

I don't know why it cannot be imported..

Comment: Seems like your path lacks some backslashes.

Comment: Which GRASS version are you using?

Comment: im using GRASS v6.4.0. when i loaded the file, it loaded the path in this way "C:UsersRhenDesktopPHPH.tx". i loaded it via the File>Import Vector Data>Geonames Import and it displayed that error.

Comment: According to our tests I managed to solved the problem. Available in recent binary snapshots, see below.

Answer (score 4):

I have identified some variable quoting problems in the code (causing troubles with white space in the path and such) and fixed it. A few hours ago a new winGRASS binary snapshot was built, you can download it here:

http://josef.fsv.cvut.cz/wingrass/grass64/
-> WinGRASS-6.4.SVN-r45245-1-Setup.exe  (or more recent)

I hope it works now. Alternatively, you can also simply substitute the v.in.geonames
script in your installation with [this corrected file](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/branches/releasebranch_6_4/scripts/v.in.geonames/v.in.geonames?format=txt). Please let us know how it goes.

Comment: More fixes applied, it likely works now. You may grab the updated script here [1] or get the tomorrow's binary snapshot (see above) or wait for GRASS 6.4.1RC2.   [1] http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/branches/releasebranch_6_4/scripts/v.in.geonames/v.in.geonames?rev=45247&format=txt

Comment: The new snapshot binary is ready: http://josef.fsv.cvut.cz/wingrass/grass64/ -> WinGRASS-6.4.SVN-r45255-1-Setup.exe

Comment: I installed the WinGRASS-6.4.SVN-r45255-1-Setup.exe. The geonames text file had been read but it displayed another error: `ERROR: This module only operates in LatLong/WGS84 locations`. The geonames file is not yet displayed on the map.

Comment: Glad that the problem is solved. To *use* the module, as stated, you need to use a LatLong/WGS84 location to import these data. Then you can reproject to another (suitable) projection. Note, that GRASS comes with a demolocation which is LatLong/WGS84 which you could use. Or create a new one with the location wizard (click through or use EPSG code 4326 in the code selector). Enjoy.

Comment: I was able to load the geonames file. Thanks! It only displayed a lot of x on the raster map. I think those are the centroids, I'm not sure what it is called. The names of the places are not loaded. Is there a problem with the way I loaded it? I loaded it by using the GRASS interface: File>Import Vector Data>Geonames Import. Or is it the .txt  file that I'm using that is wrong? I downloaded PH.zip from: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Comment: Yes, the x are the centroids. To have labels, you need to activate them (esp. choose the column to display!). So, when you select the vector map to be displayed, the dialog contains "Display selected attribute based on 'attrcol' (i.e. attribut column). Go also to the "Labels" tab and select the column. That's it and you see the map with labels.